# How to print the labels of a tensor flow dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, python-3.7

I would like to know what are the available labels in a particular dataset. In the code i know the labels , but I want it to be printed from the dataset assuming if I don't know all the labels. is there a way to do that?

I couldn't find a solution for this in web.

```
splits = tfds.Split.ALL.subsplit(weighted=(70,30))

(training_set, validation_set),dataset_info = tfds.load('tf_flowers', with_info = True , as_supervised = True,split = splits)

num_classes = dataset_info.features['label'].num_classes

num_training_examples = 0
num_validation_examples = 0

for example in training_set:
  num_training_examples += 1

for example in validation_set:
  num_validation_examples += 1

print('Total Number of Classes: {}'.format(num_classes))
print('Total Number of Training Images: {}'.format(num_training_examples))
print('Total Number of Validation Images: {} \n'.format(num_validation_examples))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class_names = np.array(dataset_info.features['label'].names)